# P0406 Error - Ford Figo

Tags: ford, sensor, figo

I bought a second hand Ford Figo 2011. The vehicle has driven around 56k kilometres. Recently there was an issue with the starter motor, which I got fixed. After that the Check light is on. The Ford service executive suggested I should replace the EGR valve, but I think the light is on because of some loose connection (the mechanic who repaired started motor did struggle while removing it)

What should I do in this case? Should I get it replaced? I'm asking because I've no idea about this, this is my first car. If I consult any mechanic they would suggest I replace it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you mean ***EGR*** (Exhaust Gas Recirculation)? P0406 has to do with an EGR problem. Of course, look at the easy things first like the wiring, but ultimately it could be the valve itself.

Comment: Yes, I meant EGR 